# Difference between B'racha She'eina Tzaricha and B'racha L'vatala

Tags: blessing, halacha-theory, bracha-levatala

I've seen both these terms in halachic sources, in reference to a B'racha that should not have been made. But I'm not sure what the difference is.

Comment: In short, a berakhah lebhatala is one that is altogether unlicensed (e.g. making a leshev on hanukah, saying a berakhah over a food item and then not eating anything, etc). A berakhah she'enah serikhah is an occasion where one has caused an additional berakhah to have to be recited, whereas one could have construed the circumstance otherwise and reduced the amount of berakhoth recited (eg reciting a berakhah over an individual food item immediately before commencing a bread based meal that could have had hamosi cover all).

Answer (score 1):

They are related but they are not the same. The way I recall this being explained to me in a halacha shiur is from the example given for a b'racha she'eina tzaricha being making a bracha or brachos on food when ultimately one is going to wash soon afterwards. These brachos would not be l'vatala because one needs to make a bracha before eating but they would be she'eina tzaricha because if that person would have washed first then they wouldn't have made those brachos.

A bracha l'vatala on the other hand is a bracha that should not be made at all. For example making the bracha al netilas yedoyim when washing was a chumra and not an obligation or repeating a bracha that was already said within the timeframe the original bracha still applies.

Comment: The mishna brura says the same thing: משנה ברורה סימן רטו ס"ק יח
(יח) ברכה שאינה צריכה - כגון שמברך בתוך הסעודה על דברים שנפטרו כבר ע"י ברכת המוציא דזו הברכה שלא לצורך היא כלל ועוד כתבו הפוסקים דאפילו אם עכשיו לא היה הברכה לבטלה ג"כ היא לפעמים בכלל ברכה שאינה צריכה כגון אם שלחנו ערוך לפניו ודעתו לילך וליטול ידיו ולאכול ולוקח קודם הנטילה ומברך על דברים שדעתו לאכלם בתוך הסעודה ג"ז אסור דגורם ברכה שאינה צריכה וכ"ש המפסיק בין הברכה לעשיה דגורם שתתבטל הברכה הראשונה לגמרי בודאי אסור ועיין לעיל בסימן מ"ו במ"ב סקי"ד ובמ"א בסימן זה לענין השלמת מאה ברכות בשבת: